# No paste event when shift key is down in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, paste

In Firefox, I do not get a 'paste' event when the shift key is held down. I do get this event in Chrome. How do I get the 'paste' event when the shift key is held down?

[See this jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/geqogiwozo/edit?html,js,output)
This is what I am using to capture the paste event:

```
['cut', 'copy', 'paste'].forEach(function(event) {
  document.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
    alert(event);
  });
});
```

**Edit for some context:**
Paste with the shift key (CTRL+SHIFT+V or CMD+SHIFT+V) is a common "Paste without formatting" command. In Google Docs, this command works in Firefox. I assume Google Docs is listening to the "paste" event, as that is the only way to retrieve clipboard data in Firefox. How is Google Docs retrieving the "paste" event?

Is it possible to get clipboard data when doing a "Paste without formatting" keyboard command?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion Firefox has the correct behavior because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is a *different* keyboard shortcut than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (this is more evident if you have worked with keyboard shortcuts in desktop applications). I tried the example in MS Edge and it has the same behavior than Firefox.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> works in Chrome because nothing prevent applications for using also this or another additional shortcuts for paste. For example pressing it in Windows Notepad paste the text but in Notepad++ inserts the special char `SYN` (whatever it means).

I tried several programs that work with text (IDEs, text editors...) and almost all ignore <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for pasting, including Microsoft Word and Excel, although edit and combo boxes based on the [Windows standard edit control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458(v=vs.85).aspx) seems to accept it to paste text by default. Maybe this is what made you think that the "shifted" version of the shortcut is always used for paste (and maybe this is the reason why Chrome accept that shortcut for paste).

Comment: Firefox is 99% of the time correct. it is a real browser, not a hack like Chrome

Comment: I think both browsers reflect people behind them: Firefox comes from the open source community and enthusiastic programmers and Chrome comes from a big multinational. The first ones have the objective of making a browser for the people and favor correct behavior at the expense of other things (sometimes confusing non technical people, although this is changing). The second ones had the objective of replace IE as fast as possible (with great success) in their master plan to move people from the "Microsoft desktop" to the "Google web", so they have at best a pragmatic approach about correctness.

Answer (score 0):

This may be intentional. In the case of context menus shift+rightclick bypasses javascript so that users can still use the standard context menu even when javascript modifies or blocks it on regular rightclick.